# Error running while executing "docker exec" on running containers

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have been trying to execute below commands on my running container but every time I execute any command it gives me an error. The image is for windows containers

```
docker exec "Container name" cat /etc/hosts
docker exec "Container name" bash
docker exec "Container name" sh
```

this is the error I get

```
container 765e4e8d647d54051c1926e591666b87d1e6e95187920f9e42f6b62b97ff508e encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF6B747AE77: (caller: 00007FF6B742E4AB) Exception(3) tid(798) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info: {"CommandLine":"cat /etc/host","WorkingDirectory":"/","Environment":{"COMPLUS_NGenProtectedProcess_FeatureEnabled":"0","DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER":"true","ROSLYN_COMPILER_LOCATION":"c:\\RoslynCompilers\\tools"},"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}
PS C:\windows\system32> docker exec angry_pascal cat /etc/host
container 765e4e8d647d54051c1926e591666b87d1e6e95187920f9e42f6b62b97ff508e encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF6B747AE77: (caller: 00007FF6B742E4AB) Exception(4) tid(638) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info: {"CommandLine":"cat /etc/host","WorkingDirectory":"/","Environment":{"COMPLUS_NGenProtectedProcess_FeatureEnabled":"0","DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER":"true","ROSLYN_COMPILER_LOCATION":"c:\\RoslynCompilers\\tools"},"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}
```

I went through [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) and some Github forums as well but I couldn't find a solution to it. Below is my docker file

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet
COPY ./bin/Release/PublishOutput .
```

Its a very basic docker file, so I am not sure if I am missing something or I am doing something wrong. Any help on this would be appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `/etc/host` file won't be inside container because you're missing last `s`.

Also I don't know much about Windows containers but my wild guess would be that linux binaries such as `sh`, `bash` or `cat` are not available in Windows. Instead you should invoke `powershell.exe` for example as described here:

https://www.ntweekly.com/2019/09/20/how-to-attach-to-a-running-windows-container/

Comment: I edited the answer.. Windows use different filesystem structure so I'd say hosts file is somewhere in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` - also you must use some equivalent of cat such as `type file.txt`

Comment: So when I follow the post that you have linked I get this ```service 'w3svc' failed APPCMD failed with error code 4312 Failed to update IIS configuration ```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Ordrej Bardon that I wasn't using windows commands to interact with my container and instead of using `sh`,`bash` or `cat` I should use `powershell.exe` or `cmd.exe`. This would solve one part of the problem but would start giving

```
service 'w3svc' failed
APPCMD failed with error code 4312
Failed to update IIS configuration
```

To solve this problem refer to [Can't run microsoft/aspnet interactively](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-docker/issues/64). Here the solution and explanation of this problem is given
Solution :
Changes in Dockerfile
Add `ENTRYPOINT["powershell"]`

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet
ENTRYPOINT["powershell"]
COPY ./bin/Release/PublishOutput .
```

Explanation:

> The entrypoint is defined as ENTRYPOINT ["C:\ServiceMonitor.exe", "w3svc"]. When you add cmd.exe as the run parameter, it is attempting to add that as an argument after ServiceMonitor.exe w3svc.
> With that Dockerfile, you could then do docker build -t aspnet . and then run it interactively by docker run -it aspnet.